# Hebrew 11:24 : From where this information was taken (targum ? talmud ? …)?

Tags: hebrews, moses, manuscript

"*By faith Moses, when he was come to years, refused to be called the son of Pharaoh's daughter;*" Hebrew 11:24 - KJV

From where this information was taken (targum ? talmud ? …) ?

Thanks for any help.
Gustav.

Comment: From the Hebrew Bible. Moses chose to abandon Pharaoh's palace after executing the Egyptian oppressor (Exodus 2:11-14), rather than continuing to partake of the rights and lifestyle afforded to him by his adoption into the royal house.

Comment: @Lucian The question is asking about the _source_. Since the actual wording about Pharoah's daughter is not in Exodus, the OP assumes the information comes from verbal communciation and tradition (this, possibly written down in later centuries). Someone needs to access the written Targum and Talmud and report on it.

Comment: @NigelJ: He forfeited his royal rights and privileges, which he had by virtue of being the (adopted) son of Pharaoh's daughter.

Comment: @Lucian Yes, I agree. But the OP wants more.

Comment: @Well I was hoping someone with the knowledge would just have a peek at the stated documents and report back.

Answer (score 2):

Louis H. Feldman connects Hebrews 11:24 with the 1st-century Jewish writer Philo.

Here is a quote from an article called *Philo's View of Moses Birth and Upbringing* which is published in the *Catholic Biblical Quarterly*, April 2002.

> Moses, even though he was the exceedingly prosperous heir apparent to the throne who was regularly called the young king, showed zeal for the culture of his kinsmen and ancestors. On the one hand, he regarded the good fortune of his adopters as spurious; and on the other hand, though his natural parents were less distinguished, he looked upon them as his own and genuine. (Philo Mos. 1.6.31-7.32)

According to Feldman, Philo emphasizes that Moses gave up everything he had for his people when he could have easily stayed in the lap of luxury.

Here is a screenshot of the text in question. Link is found [here](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/text/philo/book24.html):

[image]

This may not be the final word - but I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it helps thanks

Comment: @gustav.b This link wasn't working last night when I posted. a great site for non-biblical writings.  www.earlyjewishwritings.com and www.earlychristianwritings.com.  Here is the text for Philo: 
http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/text/philo/book24.html

Answer (score 0):

Jewish legends and fables were many, even Josephus was not immune to use them liberally. These stories added "meat" to the "bone" of Exodus Chapter 2.
So, the sources may not be as important as the fact that Paul used it to emphasize his point.

Comment: I don’t agree with that sorry.

Comment: Does the fact that Paul quotes from extra-biblical sources (e.g. Acts 17:28, 1 Cor 15:33) to emphasize his points that big of a deal? Is one's faith compromised somehow?
(Sorry, this may not directly answer your original question.)

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand what you mean.